# Visual Studio Code autocomplete when I press "." key. Any way to disable?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

When I'm trying to extend the React.Component abstract base class, I get autocomplete suggestions in the box below as I type in React. The problem is they complete even when I type in the "." key, rather than tab or enter as one would expect.

[image]

Is there any way to disable this behavior, so that I don't get autocomplete with the dot key. I guess a workaround could be to get an extension that would make more React related suggestions/snippets pop up. So far I had no luck with trying some of those out. I also didn't find anything related to this in keybindings.

I tried disabling all of my extensions that have anything to do with intellisense, autocomplete or snippets (note that I have many), but it seems to be coming from within VSCode itself.

Comment: I didn't quite get why on your screenshot there is no dot of which you're speaking about. From what I see it's an autocomplete popup which you brought up using some other combination, did you?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```json
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
```

Comment: in case anyone else is new to VS Code and isn't sure where to put this: Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P) > Preferences: Open Settings (JSON) > add within curly braces and save

Comment: @CaseyL in that case, one also can follow:
File -> Preferences -> Settings and there search for "suggestion"
there you can turn off both 'Accept Suggestion On Commit Character' and 'Accept Suggestion On Enter' (i dont like editor takes over so much)