# Disable Autocomplete on . (dot) in VSCode

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code

Example: trying to type `return res.data`

after typing the `.` it autocompletes to `return resizeBy`.

Have already turned off autocomplete on enter, and don't want to turn off `editor.quickSuggestions` completely as I still like the menu coming up (just not taking over too much).

Can't find very much about this online at all.

Comment: check this, maybe this is what u are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911977/prevent-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: thanks - I had a look at that earlier but none of the settings actually apply. i'm happy to keep the visual suggestions, just want to disable the hotkey to accept them (I need something like  editor.acceptSuggestionOnDot)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code autocomplete when I press "." key. Any way to disable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609354/visual-studio-code-autocomplete-when-i-press-key-any-way-to-disable)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

place this in your `settings.json` file:

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
```

To open `settings.json` file:

1. `cmd +` , or `ctrl +`,
2. scroll down until you see `Files: Associations`
3. Click on `edit` in `settings.json`
4. paste the code above and save.

Comment: Trying to go from Atom to Code, and this was doing my head in; especially when trying to spread data within JS. Thanks!

Comment: Additional to this, if you want to stop the popover from appearing when entering a dot, then set `"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false`

Answer (score 9):

1. open vs code editor.
2. under left hand corner => click `setting`
3. "text editor" => `suggestion`.
4. uncheck the `Accept Suggestion On Commit Character` (it could be placed on the first line of suggestion)