# How to avoid ellipsis in VSCode autocompletion?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

How to avoid `...` from appearing in VSCode autocompletion? It shows the identifier name twice. Like in this case:

- `readFile...`
- `function readFileSync`

But I rather have it shown only once to make it easier for me to see it. I am not sure why the developers of VS Code decided to change it in such way. Earlier there was no ellipsis and the autocompletion identifier was shown only once.

[image]

Comment: This is language-specific. Can you add a language tag?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the following setting as answered by @nick-daria in [Disable Autocomplete on . (dot) in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447663/disable-autocomplete-on-dot-in-vscode):

```json
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
```