# Visual Studio Code: typing dot after "props" causes it to autocomplete to "ImagePropTypes" - why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am doing a React Native tutorial and using Visual Studio Code. My selected language mode is [Babel Javascript](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel).

When typing Line 7 as shown here:

[image]

As soon as I add a period (`.`) to `props`, it changes to `ImagePropTypes.`:

[image]

Why does this behavior occur, and how do I prevent it from happening?

**Note:** I realize I have a mistake here, that I am already destructuring `props` to `{item, navigation}` in `MealTile`'s function parameter, so I can't actually reference `props` inside the function. When I do not do this (i.e. if I simply pass `props` as a parameter instead), the `props` -> `ImagePropTypes` change does not occur. Can someone still explain what is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode has some [IntelliSense features](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_intellisense-features) and one of them is triggering by a character.

> You can trigger IntelliSense in any editor window by typing `Ctrl+Space` or by typing a trigger character (such as the dot character (.) in JavaScript).

In your snippet, the auto-suggest on the phrase "props" gives you `ImagePropTypes` because you don't have any `props` value in the scope, then by pressing `.` you pick the first option.

- [IntelliSense in VSCode](http://ntelliSense)

Comment: Thanks Dennis, this helps explain. I've disabled this behavior using the `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,` snippet per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48609930/3700490